# C# delete dynamically added textbox and move all other textboxes down

Tags: c#, winforms

I have really been struggling with this question for a long time.

I add a textbox and a button on tab press . I put text inside the textboxes:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1HVj.png]

Now, my question, how do I remove the textbox next to the button I click and move all the textboxes down, so I won't get any open space. If I press on the button next to the 7th textbox, I want it to look like this:

[image]

here's my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //creates a textbox(t0) and a button(b0) on load
        TextBox t0 = new TextBox();
        t0.Name = "t0";
        t0.Location = new Point(16, 12);
        t0.Width = 200;
        t0.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(PreviewKeyDown);

        Button b0 = new Button();
        b0.TabStop = false;
        b0.Text = "x";
        b0.Location = new Point(216, 11);
        b0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 22);
        b0.Click += new EventHandler(buttonclicked);

        panel1.Controls.Add(t0);
        panel1.Controls.Add(b0);
    }



    private new void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        //if I press tab in the last textbox it creates a new textbox(t + amount of textboxes) and button(b + amount of textboxes)
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            int counter2 = 0;
            foreach (TextBox box in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                counter2++;
            }

            counter2 = counter2 - 1;
            string Name = "t" + Convert.ToString(counter2);
            counter2++;
            foreach (TextBox box in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (Name == box.Name && box.Focused)
                {
                    TextBox t0 = new TextBox();
                    Button b0 = new Button();

                    t0.Location = new Point(16, 12 + counter - panel1.VerticalScroll.Value);
                    t0.Width = 200;
                    t0.Name = "t" + Convert.ToString(counter2);
                    t0.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(PreviewKeyDown);

                    b0.TabStop = false;
                    b0.Text = "x";
                    b0.Name = "b" + Convert.ToString(counter2);
                    b0.Location = new Point(216, 11 + counter - panel1.VerticalScroll.Value);
                    b0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 22);
                    b0.Click += new EventHandler(buttonclicked);

                    panel1.Controls.Add(t0);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(b0);

                    counter = counter + 25;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void buttonclicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove the textbox next to it.
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx). Set the `GrowStyle` on the TableLayoutPanel to `AddRows` or `AddColumns` and then you can add/remove controls to it and it will resize automatically. Set the height of each row to a number a little bigger than the height of the textbox. Set the column widths to a value so the textbox and the button can fit in them. You need 2 columns in it.

You do not need to set the location of the controls to a static location. They will be handled by the `TableLayoutPanel` for you.

Here is how you can add new controls to it.

```
yourTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(yourTextbox1, 0 /* Column Index */, 0 /* Row index */);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After all these hours of work, this kind of simple trick worked.  I only needed 1 column and 2 rows btw.

Sorry, but I haven't got enough rep points to upvote.

Comment: Glad it worked out. No worries mate,  you will soon have many points with such a good attitude.